# Size difference between an iso file burnt to a cd and the file retrieved with dd

Tags: linux, dd, iso, dvd

I have an iso file (`foo.iso`) that I burnt to a dvd with the command :

```
growisofs -dvd-compat -Z /dev/cdrom=foo.iso
```

I then tried the command

```
dd if=/dev/cdrom of=foo2.iso
```

However, `foo2.iso` is larger by a few kB. What explains this difference? How can I retrieve the original file from a cd?

EDIT: Simply removing the extra bytes from `foo2.iso` gives the original file as proven by a checksum. So another question: Is foo2.iso a valid iso file even with the extra junk bytes? This would be important in case I don't have access to the original file's size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `dd` reads when you run `dd if=/dev/cdrom of=foo2.iso` is not a file (there is no such thing on a physical CD), but a number of 4KB sectors.  If the length of the image file you wrote is not an exact multiple of 4KB = 4096, there will be some padding at the end.  You can safely ignore it.